# Como preencher datagrid em um form com campos em outro form C#?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview, sql-server-2012

Eu estou fazendo um sistema de fidelidade, e queria **usar dois forms para os clientes**, **o form1 com o *datagridview* e um botão cadastrar** e o outro **form2 com os campos dos dados a serem preenchidos**, esse **form2** seria acionado ao pressionar o botão cadastrar no **form1**, daí **quando salvasse os dados no form2 eles apareçam no *datagridview* do form1**.
Alguém pode me ajudar??

Answer (score 1):

```
   DataGridViewButtonCell b = new DataGridViewButtonCell();
        int rowIndex = MainTable.Rows.Add(b);
        MainTable.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Value = "name";
```

**Assim?**

Answer (score 0):

No Form1

1 - Crie um Grid

2 - Crie um botao Cadastrar no Form1 e adicione o evento de Click:

```
private void Cadastrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     new Frm2().ShowDialog();
     Grid.DataSource = ConsultarClienteGravadosBancoDados();
     Grid.RefreshDataSource();
}
```

No Form2

1 - Adicione os TextEdit com os campos para o cadastro de Cliente

2 - Crie um botao Salvar no Form2 e adiciove o evento de Click:

```
private void Salvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     cliente.Codigo = textEdit1.Text;
     cliente.Nome = textEdit2.Text;
     InserirClienteBancoDados(cliente);

     this.Close();
}
```